# JSON data store in POSTGRES (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink

I would like to deisgn a database and model like below for eclipseLink and POSTGRES.

What would be the best approach to do the same? How ro store JSON data in Postgres and retrieve?

My data model is something like below.

```
NAMES               SURNAMES
id name             id         JSON
1   test            100        {test:temp, test2:dfdf, test3:fsdf}

Mapping
namesId surnamesId  place        country 
1       100        San Jose      CA
```

Comment: PostgreSQL and EclpseLink versions? While PostgreSQL 9.2 can store JSON natively, it can't do tons with it, and it's usually much better to map it to relational structures. There's lots of support for that in JAXP with JSON extensions, or using tools like Jersey.

Answer (score 3):

You can store JSON in any character column (VARCHAR, TEXT).  If you want to use the JSON type you may need to use a Converter to convert between it and your field type.

If you want to convert your JSON data to objects, you can use JAXB with EclipseLink Moxy to do this.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy#MOXy.27s_JSON-Binding

You could write your own converter for this, or in the EclipseLink 2.6 dev stream there is a new JSON Convert option.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/406993